# How can I stop the videobackground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I stop the videobackground when I move to another viewcontroller? 
because when I move to another viewcontroller, the video and background music continue to be played, and when I go back to the main page two videos overlap. so I would like the video and the music to stop when I move to another viewcontroller, such as when I move in the viewcontroller for the sign up

```
import UIKit
import SwiftVideoBackground
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let videoBackground = VideoBackground()

@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mute_img: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet private var muteSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {



    if (sender.isOn == true)
    {
        mute_img.isHidden = false
        videoBackground.isMuted = true
    }
    else
    {
        mute_img.isHidden = true
        videoBackground.isMuted = false
    }

    let shouldMute = sender.isOn
    videoBackground.isMuted = shouldMute
    UserDefaults.standard.set(shouldMute, forKey:"isMuted")
   }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let shouldMute = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
    videoBackground.play(view: view, videoName: "intro", videoType: 
    "mp4", isMuted: shouldMute, willLoopVideo : true)
    muteSwitch.isOn = shouldMute


    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == usernameField {
        passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == passwordField {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Save UISwitch state in UserDefault

Comment: can you write the code?

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey:"isMuted")` write this line in your switch action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps:

1) Make an IBOutlet for the switch

```
@IBOutlet private var muteSwitch: UISwitch!
```

Don't forget to connect it to the switch in the storyboard.

2) Read the saved value from UserDefaults ( in viewDidLoad ):

```
override 
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let shouldMute = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
    videoBackground.play(view: view, videoName: "intro", videoType: "mp4", isMuted: shouldMute, alpha : 0.25, willLoopVideo : true)
    muteSwitch.isOn = shouldMute
}
```

3) Save the switch value to UserDefaults ( in @IBAction func `switch`...) :

```
@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let shouldMute = sender.isOn
    videoBackground.isMuted = shouldMute
    UserDefaults.standard.set(shouldMute, forKey:"isMuted")
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS... THANK YOU

Comment: How can I stop the video when I move to another viewcontroller?

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userDefaults.value(forKey: "isMuted") != nil{

        let object = userDefaults.value(forKey: "isMuted") as? NSNumber
        yourSwitch.isOn = (object?.boolValue)!
    }
}
@IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    let uDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    if sender.isOn {
        uDefault.setValue(NSNumber(value: true), forKey:"isMuted")

    }
    else {
        uDefault.setValue(NSNumber(value: false), forKey:"isMuted")

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey` while there is already `boolForKey`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will take care

Answer (score -1):

- **1. Objective - C Version**

  #import "ViewController.h"

  ```
  @interface ViewController ()

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *bluetoothSwitch;

  - (IBAction)saveSwitchState:(id)sender;

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      if ([defaults objectForKey:@"SwitchState"])
          self.bluetoothSwitch.on = [defaults boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  - (IBAction)saveSwitchState:(id)sender
  {
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      if ([self.bluetoothSwitch isOn]) 
          [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchState"];
      else 
         [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchState"];
  }
  @end
  ```
- **Swift Version**

  import UIKit

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var stateSwitch: UISwitch!

      @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
          if stateSwitch.isOn {
              textField.text = "The Switch is Off"
              stateSwitch.setOn(false, animated:true)
          } else {
              textField.text = "The Switch is On"
              stateSwitch.setOn(true, animated:true)
          }
      }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          stateSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stateChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
      }

      @objc func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch) {
          if switchState.isOn {
              textField.text = "The Switch is On"
          } else {
              textField.text = "The Switch is Off"
          }
      }

      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
          super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
          // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }


  }
  ```